# Is there any tensorflow version of numpy.view_as_windows?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I am working with python3 and tensorflow to generate image patches by using numpy `view_as_windows` but because of numpy can't run on GPU, is there any way to do it with tensorflow?

ex: `view_as_windows(array2d, window_shape, stride)`

Thanks

Comment: Do you need these patches inside a Tensoflow graph afterwards, or would this be just for "fast" patch generation?

Comment: I think I want this just to be fast patch generation because I still need to modify it afterward. Actually I am new with this tensorflow so if you have any advice, it would be really great :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: This answer does **not** answer the OP's exact question, but addresses the actual need of the OP as clarified in the comments (i.e., generate image patches, quickly). I just thought this would fit better here than in a badly-formatted comment.

*If all you need to do is generating image patches*, Tensorflow (and generally GPU acceleration) is not the right tool for this, because the actual computation is trivial (extract a sub-area of an image) and the bottleneck would be memory transfer between GPU and CPU.

My suggestion is, then, to write CPU-only code that uses `view_as_windows` and parallelize it via `multiprocessing` to split the workload on all your CPU cores.

*Should you need to feed those patches to a Tensorflow graph afterwards*, the way to go would be to first generate the patches on the CPU (with whatever input pipeline you like), batch them and *then* feed them to the GPU for the graph computation.

Comment: Thanks, nice information! I will try to look for more about this. I guess I must numpy for this.